# Running history command remotely in linux

Tags: linux, unix

My requirement is to save history of the commands into a file called history_yymmdd.txt by running the following command on a remote server.

```
history > history_20170523.txt
```

I tried with the following command, but it was creating a blank file on remote server(10.12.13.14).

```
ssh 10.12.13.14 "history > history_20170523.txt"
```

When I log in to the remote server and run the history command, then the file was created successfully.  But I need to run the command on 20 servers so creating a script to run it remotely on each server is my objective here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ssh user@machine_name "cat ~/.bash_history > history_20170523.txt"
```

The 'history' command dumps the contents of .bash_history, so this may be useful to you.

A more elegant solution might be:

```
scp user@machine_name:~/.bash_history history_20170523.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Chris for the work around.  Any idea why history command does not work?

Comment: An `ssh` session is not interactive so it will not load your history or enable other interactive features.  This is detailed in the Bash manual.

Comment: @veera - if you like this answer, please upvote and accept it

Answer (score -1):

you are doing it in a wrong way, also there is no user for the remote machine. Correct way to do is
`ssh -q -tt user@10.12.13.14 'history > history_20170523.txt'`

Comment: ohh my bad, I didn't noticed what he was trying to do. I just focused on the ssh part that ssh command is not invoked properly.